# Calculate the entropy for an arrangement of quantum particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

I am not a physicist, just read some pages of information theory, and wondered how far off this idea is:

Imagine 2 levels and 3 particles that can be distributed in those levels. Also, each state-level (the **_**) has a label, such that **_ x** and **x _** are different states.

--------Microstate 1, non degenerated-------------

**L2   _ _**

**L1 x  x  x**

-----M 2, hexa degenerated-----

**L2   _ x**

**L1  x  x  _**

(and 5 other combinations)

---------------M3, triple-degenerated-------------

**L2   x x**

**L1  x  _  _**

(and two other combinations)

---

the Shannon (or Boltzmann) formula is $$ H = - p_1\cdot\log(p_1) - 2p_2\cdot\log(p_2) - 3p_3\cdot \log(p_3)$$

The total number of microstates is 10:

$$H = -\frac1{10}\cdot\log_2\left(\frac1{10}\right) - \frac6{10}\cdot\log_2\left(\frac6{10}\right) - \frac3{10}\cdot\log_2\left(\frac3{10}\right) = 1.3$$

This means that most of the time it is enough to specify a single bit of information to determine the state.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I did.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If it's "is this calculation correct", then I'm afraid that "check-my-work" questions are considered off-topic on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a statement of the problem that only two of the three particles can be in level L2? If you can also find three particles in state L2, then the computation of the number of configurations is not correct.

Your computation of the entropy only stands if particles in L1 and L2 have the same energy. From a physical perspective, the postulate of equiprobability only applies to micro-states with the same energy. Say that particles in state L1 (L2) have energy E1 (E2). Then the probability to find the system in any of the configurations M2 of your example would be:

$P_{M2}= \mathcal{Z}^{-1}e^{-\beta(2E1+E2)}$

Given that the energy of the system is $2E1+E2$  and that only two particles can be in state L2, it is true that the probability to find the system in one of the six possible configurations compatible with such energy is 1/6.

Comment: L1, L2 are not particles, are states, with same energies, just labelled differently.

Comment: I am trying to compute the entropy, and the states are equiprobable, maybe remove energy from the picture, it is simpler what I try to do.

Comment: @MahNeh What is your question exactly?